# InsertAfter Function in a singly linked list (C)

Tags: c

I have to write a code for inserting a new node with value after the first node that contains the findValue.If the findValue is not in the list, insert the new node as the tail of the linked list.

I get a segmentation fault when I try to insert something. Looking for why that happens and what the mistake is in the code.

```
void insertAfter(listNode **listPtr, int findValue, int value) {    
  while((*listPtr)->next != NULL){
    if((*listPtr)->value == findValue){
      listNode *newNodePtr = (listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
      newNodePtr->value    = value;
      newNodePtr->next     = (*listPtr)->next;
      (*listPtr)->next     = newNodePtr;
      (*listPtr)           = (*listPtr)->next;
    }
    if((*listPtr)->next == NULL){
      listNode *newNodePtr = (listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
      newNodePtr->value    = value;
      newNodePtr->next     = NULL;
      (*listPtr)->next     = newNodePtr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger like gdb/ddd and get a backtrace?  thats the best way to catch segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

Your indention doesn't match your braces. Before:

```
while((*listPtr)->next !=NULL){
  if((*listPtr)->value ==findValue){
  }
if((*listPtr)->next ==NULL){
   }
}
```

after:

```
while((*listPtr)->next !=NULL){
  if((*listPtr)->value ==findValue){
  }
}
if((*listPtr)->next ==NULL){
}
```

We generally don't like code with messed-up indentation. It's hard to see what's wrong. But that code still won't work because more errors. Let's try this:

```
while((*listPtr)->next !=NULL){
  if((*listPtr)->value ==findValue) {
    listNode *newNodePtr=(listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNodePtr->value = value;
    newNodePtr->next = (*listPtr)->next;
    (*listPtr)->next =newNodePtr;
    return;
  }
  listPtr = &((*listPtr)->next); /* advancer was really messed up */
}
if((*listPtr)->next ==NULL){
  listNode *newNodePtr = (listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
  newNodePtr->value = value;
  newNodePtr->next = NULL;
  (*listPtr)->next=newNodePtr;
}
```

But we can remove a lot of duplication:

```
while((*listPtr) != NULL){
  if((*listPtr)->value ==findValue) {
    break;
  }
  listPtr = &((*listPtr)->next);
}
listNode *newNodePtr = (listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
newNodePtr->value = value;
newNodePtr->next = (*listPtr)->next;
(*listPtr)->next=newNodePtr;
```

Or even more succinctly:

```
for(;*listPtr && (*listPtr)->value != findValue;
    listPtr = &((*listPtr)->next)) { }
struct listNode *newNodePtr = malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
newNodePtr->value = value;
newNodePtr->next = (*listPtr)->next;
(*listPtr)->next=newNodePtr;
```

At this point, the rest of the bugs in the original code are addressable:

```
for(;*listPtr && (*listPtr)->value != findValue;
    listPtr = &((*listPtr)->next)) { }
struct listNode *newNodePtr = malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
if (*listPtr) { /* it's insert after, not insert before, but we have to handle not finding anything and putting it on the end */
    newNodePtr->value = *listPtr->value;
    *listPtr->value = value;
} else {
    newNodePtr->value = value;
}
newNodePtr->next = *listPtr; /* Don't try to follow next off the end */
*listPtr = newNodePtr;
```

Comment: error: called object ‘(*listPtr)->next’ is not a function

Comment: @coderx123: You know what, next time I get one like this I'm blanking the original code and just writing another one. Much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your `*listPtr` is NULL you will get a seg fault at this line:
`while((*listPtr)->next !=NULL){`

This is the first line in your function.

Try following code. I have added appropriate checks and also removed unnecessary clutter:

```
void insertAfter(listNode **listPtr, int findValue, int value) {

    listNode * newNodePtr = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNodePtr->value = value;
    newNodePtr->next = NULL;


    if ((*listPtr) == NULL ){
    (*listPtr) = newNodePtr;
    return;
    }

    while ( (*listPtr)->next != NULL ){    

    if ((*listPtr)->value ==findValue){
        newNodePtr->next = (*listPtr)->next;
        (*listPtr)->next =newNodePtr;
        return;
    }   
    (*listPtr) = (*listPtr)->next;
    }


    (*listPtr)->next =newNodePtr;

}
```

Lastly I was wondering why are you taking pointer to pointer. This way you will modify the original pointer. I think you should not do this. You should only modify a **COPY** of the pointer and not the original pointer. Since I believe this pointer is the head of the Linked List.

I recommend changing `listNode **listPtr` to `listNode *listPtr` and modifying the definition accordingly.